# PHP SQLite query failing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a class for getting information from the database:

```php
    <?php
    require('dbConn.php');
      class Category {
        public static function getCategories () {
          $dbConn = SQLiteConnection::connect();
          try {
            if($sqlGetCategories = $dbConn->query("SELECT name FROM nfc_category")){
              return $sqlGetCategories->fetch();
            } else {
              print_r(get_defined_vars());
              return array('Could not get categories');
            }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
          }
        }
      }
    ?>
```

`dbConn` is just a PDO object. The issue is where the query is made in the try catch. The query returns false. The SQL is valid, why is it returning false?

Comment: The only explanation is that the table is empty.

Comment: @Barmar i am 100% sure that the table is not empty. There is nothing wrong with the SQL. The error is in the PHP.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the PHP. Note that your function only returns the first category name, not all the category names.

Comment: Which statement is returning `false`? `$sqlGetCategories = ...` or `return $sqlGetCategories->fetch()`?

Comment: @Barmar it is the if statement. The condition returns false, and moves to the else block

Comment: Do you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled? If so, a failed query should throw an exception, not return `FALSE`, so you should never get to the `else` block. If not, you should use [`PDO::errorInfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to get the reason for the error.

Comment: I printed the errorInfo and it says the table does not exist, even though it does. Why would this be? I have used this SQLiteConnection class elsewhere in the application and it worked fine.

Comment: Did you select the database?

Comment: No way to tell from what you've posted, but it's clearly not a problem with this PHP.

Comment: Could it be an issue with where the code is run from? I was trying to run that getCategories function from the page which the data will be displayed on, this might cause issue with directories